# C: Write into file as multiple columns

Tags: c

I have a long array `position` and in writing it as a single column I can do the following:

```
FILE *f = fopen("testing.txt", "w"); 
for (i=0; i<18; i++){
   fprintf(f,"%d\n",position[i]);
}
```

The output (in testing.txt) is like:

```
1
3
3
5
6
7
0
37
8
34
5
3
5
6
3
1
7
8
```

How can I print to file as:

```
1 7 5 1
3 0 3 7
3 37 5 8
5 8 6
6 34 3
```

as multiple columns each has maximum length 5?

Comment: How do you know how many elements you need to put on each line of output?

Comment: @John3136 but how can i go to the second column row one after column one row 5?

Comment: @John3136 but then i need to store it as a matrix or rewrite the array `position` beforehand and use `\t`. Is this the only solution?

Comment: you need to load into an array. Then print every 5th element start at 0, then start at 1 etc

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int pos[] = {
        1,3,3,5,6,
        7,0,37,8,34,
        5,3,5,6,3,
        1,7,8
    };
    int len = sizeof(pos)/sizeof(*pos);
    int col_len = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < col_len; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j < len; j += col_len){
            printf("%2d ", pos[j]);//fprintf(f, "%2d ", pos[j])
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Only tweak would be to use `putchar ('\n');` (to make the `'\n'` explicit). Glad to see you answer one.

Answer (score 0):

your output is a little strange you have 4 elements in first and second line, and three elements in third and forth line.
In general to maintain in the same line you can print " " or '\t' - tab

```
printf("%d ", 1);
printf("%d", 2);
```

or

```
printf("%d\t", 1);
printf("%d", 2);
```

When you need to make a new line you use '\n' (like you are using)
**You have to know how much elements that you need in each particular line** to force then '\n'

Answer (score 0):

Original code

```
FILE *f = fopen("testing.txt", "w"); 
for (i=0; i<18; i++){
   fprintf(f,"%d\n",position[i]);
}
```

My guess for your request, if I understood it correctly, would be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){

int v[18] = {1,3,3,5,6,7,0,37,8,34,5,3,5,6,3,1,7,8};

int i = 0, adder = 0, done = 0;

while (1){
    if (done == 19)
        break;
    done++;
    if (i <= 18){
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
        i = i+5;
    }
    if (i > 18){
        printf("\n");
        adder++;
        i = adder;
    }
  }
}
```

You can add the file yourself. If you want an explanation, basically what I did was consider that we only have your 18 elements, and while I was not done with all of them, i counted each time I printed one of them, and when I printed them I made sure to print from 5 to 5 so that would be in a matrix form.

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(f,"%d %d...%d\n",position[i],position[i+1]...position[i+n-1]);
```

but first fix your loop